# How to display image by getting from node server?

Tags: html, css, node.js

I am trying to display an image which was in my *index.html*. This was kept in `<img` tag and whenever my server calls *index.html* file then all the paths of files included in it was also loading by checking for its own services.

All types of files like **js**, **css** and **html** are getting loaded but when it come to img files it was not loading on browser, and no error in console.

Path of an image was correct. I am using `fs.readFile()` to load files content type which was set to **image/png** as my image file was `.png`.

Can anyone make me clear what is going on here?

Comment: img tag only render a image either from file type or base64 type. Did you convert your image into base 64 ?

Comment: yes am using encoding type base64 in fs.readFile()

Comment: Did you convert base64 string to buffer ? like
var b = new Buffer('SmF2YVNjcmlwdA==', 'base64')
var s = b.toString('hex');

Comment: We can guess, but if you include your code, in a [mcve], in the question itself, we might be able to come up with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pankaj Jatav, as in html img tag is base64 decoder, our fs.readFile() encoder must be as base64, as default node has utf-8 as encoder in fs.readFile or writeFile we have to mention encoding type as base64 for images

```
    fs.readFile(filepath, 'base64', (err, file) => {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'image/png' });
            res.write(err);
            res.end();
            return;
        }
        res.writeHead(200 , { 'Content-Type': 'image/png' });
       res.end(file,'base64');
   });
```

this worked for me.